# Marketing Cloud : CreateSalesforceObject not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a custom object `Marketing_Cloud_Response__c` in Salesforce.
This object has a lookup to our Employee__c (custom object) record.

I have written the following AMPscript in Text Response

```
Salesforce record created.

%%[

var @eid 
set @eid = "a1l900055520uGlAAI"

var @response
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

var @createresponse
set @createresponse = CreateSalesforceObject("Marketing_Cloud_Response__c",2,"Employee__c",@eid,"Response__c", @response)
]%%
```

Basically, when the user responds to the SMS with a response, he/she should get "Salesforce record created"  and in background, a record will be created directly in Salesforce.

For some reason, during testing (which is why I have hardcoded the `Employee__c`), I keep on getting **`"There was an error processing your message"`**

Can someone let me know whats going wrong ?

**UPDATE :**

When I pasted the AMPscript to debug, I am getting this error

"Call to create the salesforceobject Marketing_Cloud_Response__c failed! Error status code: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY Error message: entity type cannot be inserted: Marketing Cloud Response
"

[image]

Marketing Cloud user's profile has full access (entire CRUD) on this object.

API Names of objects and fields referred in the AMPscript are correct.

There are no triggers or any validation rules on this object.

There are no record types either.

Yes...only those two fields are enough to add a record into that object.

Appreciate all inputs :)

UPDATE 2

This custom object was recently created (yesterday).
Is there a time delay before it appears in Marketing Cloud because when I try to create a synchronized data extension (just to check) the object itself is not visible !

[image]

Comment: are those two fields all you need to add to that customobject? is there validation on those fields?

Comment: @EazyE I have updated the post with more info...Please check and let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your latest update, it seems to be a visibility issue between the CRM integrated user (the connected user) and the object.

I would go to Salesforce CRM to check that user's profile and make sure the profile already has appropriate Object Permissions. E.g. Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All on `Marketing_Cloud_Response__c` object then adjust and try again.

You can check this reference [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_sets_object_perms_edit.htm&type=5) for steps.